# Запуск тестов из командной строки

Tags: java, android, terminal

Как запустить локально unit test'ы в командной строке?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку **Android Studio** использует систему сборки [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), то вы можете выполнять любые операции с вашим проектом из командной строки. Узнать все поддерживаемые операции можно при помощи команды

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

Для запуска тестов нужно использовать команду

```
./gradlew test
```